# In gedit, what is the "file browser panel" plugin and what does it do?

Tags: gedit

The "File browser panel" plugin says "Easy file access from the side panel". What side panel? The launcher maybe?

I was watching [4 Tricks to Speed Up Ubuntu - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwBoHZuauL8) and it said to turn off this plugin. I just want to understand what I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Press F9 and you will see how it works:

Plugin active:

[image]

Plugin inactive:

[image]